# NavigationLink string

Tags: swift, swiftui

im trying found right  way for this

```
    struct MainMenu: View {

    let items = [
        
        item(title: "Menu 1", image: "img1", imgColor: .orange, navMenu: "Menu1"),
        item(title: "Menu 2", image: "img2", imgColor: .orange, navMenu: "Menu2"),
```

Here is code for NavigationLink but maybe bad written. I need destination to be filled with name from navMenu. This is same like Menu1.swift and another

```
                    VStack {

                    HStack {
                    personView

                    ObjectView
                    }
                    LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: spacing)   {
                        ForEach(items) { item in
                            NavigationLink(destination: \(String(item.navMenu))()){
                                Text("")
                            } label: {
                                ItemView(item: item)
                            }
                        }
                    }

//                    .padding(.horizontal)

                }
```

In next step I make this.

```
    var body: some View {
        LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.purple, .blue]), startPoint: .topLeading, endPoint: .bottomTrailing)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

                let columns = Array(
                    repeating: GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: spacing),
                    count: numbersOfColumns)

                VStack {

                    HStack {
                    personView

                    objectView
                    }
                    LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: spacing)   {
                        ForEach(items) { item in
                            NavigationLink(destination: Text(item.navMenu)) {
                                ItemView(item: item)
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
```

but after click on item, isn't next menu called. Menu1.swift

This open only blank sheet with text Menu1

In final I need use this item in LazyVGrid like button to next *.swift file

in short description. In another *.swift file I have

```
                NavigationLink(destination: Menu1()) {
                    Button_register()
                    }
```

This code after clicking on Button lead me to next swift file called Menu1.swift

I need this same but integrated in item in LazyVGrid but path to Menu1.swift will combined from text in navMenu.

Sorry maybe I saying bad.

Comment: I'm not totally clear on what you're trying to do, but I *think* you're looking for `NavigationLink(destination: Text(item.navMenu))`

Comment: What jnpdx said. Side note: you can only do string interpolation in string literal. So you can't just do `\(...)`, you should do `"\(...)"`.

Comment: You might be looking for a guide like this [Guide](https://www.simpleswiftguide.com/how-to-add-navigationview-to-list-in-swiftui-and-show-detail-view-using-navigationlink/) Its hard to help when some information from your code is missing. When asking a question think about how you can simplify it to one question. In the title be more descriptive. Here are some links that can help you with that as well. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks for answers, I update this topic and go look on guide. Thanks all.

Comment: Here is full code https://github.com/reddogwow/test